# Double Sideband Suppressed Carrier modulator List

Tags: modulation, transmitter, dsp, amplitude-modulation

I am using ring modulator for DSB-SC  am modulation in a transmitter circuit. Can anyone please tell me about more DSB SC modulator for am modulation? I want to know which one to use where?

Comment: State your design specs first

Comment: I just want to modulate two signals. The ring mixer I have built is with 1kHz message signal and 15Khz carrier signal.

Comment: I can imagine it is so hard for you to search